# Native App Install Banner not working on iOS

Tags: ios, google-chrome, smartbanner

This manifest.json is placed per [Google instructions](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/app-install-banners/#native_app_install_banners). Android works as intended but iOS does nothing.

```
{
    "name":"FooApp",
    "short_name":"FooApp",
    "icons":[
        {
            "src":"foo_app_icon.png",
            "type":"image/png",
            "sizes":"144x144"
        }
    ],
    "prefer_related_applications":true,
    "related_applications":[
        {
            "platform":"play",
            "url":"https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.es0329.fooapp",
            "id":"com.es0329.fooapp"
        },
        {
            "platform":"itunes",
            "url":"https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/fooapp/id123456789"
        }
    ],
    "start_url":"https://www.es0329.com/fooapp",
    "display":"standalone"
}
```

Comment: did you make this work for ios?

Answer (score 0):

[Per Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest/related_applications#browser_compatibility), this function is not supported on any Safari version.

iOS has its own preferred meta tags for AppStore banners, [as defined here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/promoting_apps_with_smart_app_banners#3701576)